# ShareKit 2.0 PBXCp Error iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, github, sharekit

I'm following all steps but when i build the project following error occurs

(null): error: /Users/faxxx/Desktop/LatestVersion (shareKit-2)/ShareKit-master/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Buffer/../../../../../Submodules/buffer-ios-sdk/BufferSDK/BufferSDKResources.bundle: No such file or directory

and i can't sort out the problem i also googled it but did not understand the error

Can anyone please guide me how to solve this issue

and i am following this tutorial :

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

Please tell me how can i add sharekit to my application

Comment: Is the demo app working?